# sql element name using getname()

Tags: php, xml

I am new on PHP and xml.

This is the xml file I'm using.

```
<product product_id = '4'> 
    <category_id>5</category_id>
    <name> chocolate </name>
    <price> 120 </price>
    <unit> piece </unit>
    <quantity> 100 </quantity>
    <brandname> catberry </brandname>
    <image>NULL</image>
    <offer>NULL</offer>
</product>
```

I cannot get the children element of product.

following loop doesn't work. How can it be done?

code:

```
function update_products($id, $xml)
{
    include_once('config.php');

    foreach ($xml->children() as $key  ) {
        echo $key->getname().'</br>';
        foreach ($xml->children->children as $child ) {
            echo $child->getname();         
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: “following loop doesn't work” is vague. Can you describe your expectation and actual result? In any case, you have to change `$xml->children->children` to `$key->children()`.

Comment: never mind, got it :) it was supposed to be $xml->children() instead of $xml->children.